# How do I know when to trigger a Server-Sent-Event?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server-sent-events

### What I want to do

I'd like to use Server-Sent-Events for notifications and another feature – I don't need to go into detail for the other feature, but it requires real-time updates taken from a database just like notifications do.

### Possible alternatives

Websockets would be an option, but I think it might be a bit too much, as I only require a one-way channel for this. However I'm totally aware that I might be wrong here and Websockets could be the best option – feel free to school me on this. The current backend-setup is Node.js (Express.js webserver) with MongoDB.

### Approaches I've seen so far

I've already seen some approaches on this matter, but the main issue here is that I'd like it to be *as scalable as possible*. Having a for-Loop constantly query my database is the worst approach I've seen so far. The best approach I've seen is observing the **MongoDB oplog**, but that one seemed a bit like a hack to me rather than a good, solid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted [a link to this question on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/uqw2qy/comment/i8tqtn3/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) in the subreddit [r/node](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/) where the user /u/PremJyotish221 told me to use Redis with PUB/SUB, and let me tell you... it works *perfectly*! :)

So to anyone stumbling over this with the same problem, I can absolutely recommend it. It's fast, easy, reliable, and scalable.